# Is there a Clang function attribute for constraining an id return type?

Tags: objective-c, clang

I have a function:

`+ (id) loadClass:(Class)cls`

The return is an instance of type `cls`, not just any old `id`.  Is there a way to use GCC/Clang attributes to inform the compiler of this (so that it can perform type checking)?

For example, something like these is what I'm looking for:

`+ (instancetype(cls)) loadClass:(Class)cls`

`+ (id) loadClass:(Class)cls __attribute__((returntype=cls))`

Edit: Adding some detail to the use case

given two selectors: `-[XYZ foo]` and `-[UVW bar]` I would like:

```
[[Loader loadClass:[XYZ class]] bar] // Warning
[[Loader loadClass:[XYZ class]] foo] // OK
[[Loader loadClass:[UVW class]] bar] // OK
[[Loader loadClass:[UVW class]] foo] // Warning
```

Comment: It couldn't perform type checking even if there were such an attribute. `cls` is a variable. It could come from anywhere and have any value. The compiler can't know what it is at the point where `+loadClass:` is called in the general case. It might have been passed in from a different translation unit.

Comment: You will also face difficulty because created an instance using Class cls doesn't guarantee the instance will be of type cls  ([[loadClass: myKewlClass] class] == myKewlClass not necessarily true).

Comment: I have access to the implementation so I could add an assertion to that effect